# send parameters form objective c controller class to index.html in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios

how can i send parameters form objective c controller class to index.html in phoneGap which is javascript ?!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SetValue(newValue)"];
```

where SetValue is your own javacript setter function

Comment: Of course it works when the page loaded in webView is your index.html